# plugin leaflet does not search on the map by layer ( leaflet-fusesearch)

Tags: leaflet

I want to customize the search on the layer "Muzei" (the field 'iconCaption'), but nothing happens... Please tell me how to correct the code...

the plugin is located at this address: https://github.com/naomap/leaflet-fusesearch

data/Muzei.js

```js
var Muzei = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"metadata": {
  "name": "Музеи и галереи ",
  "creator": "Yandex Map Constructor"
},
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 0,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [104.66424966564485, 51.99642708991676]
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "Адрес: Тальцы,  47-й км Байкальского тракта\nКонтакты: тел.: 7 950 145‑40-75, 7 3952 24‑32-51\ne-mail: talci@irk.ru, talzimark@mail.ru\nсайт: http://www.talci.ru",
      "iconCaption": "Архитектурно-этнографический музей «Тальцы»",
      "marker-color": "#1e98ff"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 1,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [104.28481982936044, 52.235150415839485]
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "Адрес: Иркутск, ул. Академическая, д. 1\nКонтакты: тел.: 73952453146;\ne-mail: bm@isc.irc.ru; \nсайт: http://www.bm.isc.irk.ru",
      "iconCaption": "Байкальский музей Иркутского научного центра",
      "marker-color": "#1e98ff"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 2,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [104.28314107738336, 52.288654185599434]
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "Адрес: Иркутск, ул. Сухэ-Батора, д. 5\nКонтакты: тел.: 73952241855;  \ne-mail: irkinsect@yandex.ru;\nсайт: http://biosoil.isu.ru",
      "iconCaption": "Восточно-Сибирский музей микробиологии ИГУ",
      "marker-color": "#1e98ff"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 3,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [104.28242998112661, 52.28897985492063]
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "Адрес: Иркутск, ул. Сухэ-Батора, д. 5\nКонтакты: тел.: 73952241855;  \ne-mail: irkinsect@yandex.ru;\nсайт: http://biosoil.isu.ru",
      "iconCaption": "Восточно-Сибирский музей почвоведения им. И.В.Николаева ИГУ",
      "marker-color": "#1e98ff"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 4,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [104.28149027976227, 52.29116663064888]
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "Адрес: Иркутск, ул. Сухэ-Батора, д. 2\nКонтакты: тел.: 73952345041;  \ne-mail: krek@museum.irkutsk.ru",
      "iconCaption": "Выставочный зал «Спасская церковь»",
      "marker-color": "#1e98ff"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 5,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [104.28411953372908, 52.281967955879544]
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "Адрес: Иркутск, ул. Карла Маркса, д. 13\nКонтакты: 7 3952 20‑03-68, 7 3952 33‑62-30\nсайт: museum-irkutsk.com\n",
      "iconCaption": "Выставочный отдел «Музейная студия» Иркутского областного краеведческого музея",
      "marker-color": "#1e98ff"
    }
  },
}
}]
}
```

```js
// serach...
var searchCtrl = L.control.fuseSearch({
  position: 'topright',
  title: 'Chercher',
  placeholder: 'found objects',
  showInvisibleFeatures: false,
  showResultFct: function(feature, container) {
    props = feature.properties;
    var name = L.DomUtil.create('b', null, container);
    name.innerHTML = props.name;
    container.appendChild(L.DomUtil.create('br', null, container));
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(props.details));
  }
});
searchCtrl.addTo(map);

var streetsLayer = L.geoJson(Muzei.features, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    feature.layer = layer;
  }
});
searchCtrl.indexFeatures(streetsLayer, ['iconCaption']);
streetsLayer.addTo(map);



// or serach version 2, as in instructions
//var searchCtrl = L.control.fuseSearch()

//searchCtrl.indexFeatures(streetsLayer, ['iconCaption']);

//L.geoJson(Muzei, {
//onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
//feature.layer = layer;
//}
//});
//searchCtrl.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

code earned, it is needed to download and install fuse.js, but started another problem - the objects are on the list, but click on them with mouse is not implemented.
code is shown below. unfortunately I'm not a programmer and try to deal with the issue in the course of business...therefore, I have such difficulties with functions, etc.

var searchCtrl = L.control.fuseSearch()
    searchCtrl.addTo(map);

```
searchCtrl.indexFeatures(Muzei, ['iconCaption']);

var spots = L.geoJson(Muzei, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        feature.layer = layer;
    }
});
map.addLayer(spots)
```